# Terraform external provider - jq in bash script is giving jq: command not found

Tags: windows, powershell, terraform, git-bash

I am on Windows 10 machine, and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is installed using [choco](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/jq).

[image: jq installed]

I have a simple terraform configuration to understand external provider. And the external provider in this case is ***bash***. When I have jq to format the output, I get the following error.

```
data.external.simple-jq-test: Reading...
╷
│ Error: External Program Execution Failed
│
│   with data.external.simple-jq-test,
│   on main.tf line 8, in data "external" "simple-jq-test":
│    8:   program = ["bash", "./simple.sh"]
│
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute the program.
│
│ Program: C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe
│ Error Message: ./simple.sh: line 4: jq: command not found
│
│ State: exit status 127
╵
```

You can take a look at the full [set of files here on github repo](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureWithTerraform/tree/main/iac/3401100-external-provider-bash-simple-exmpl).

Terraform configuration is as follows.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "external" "simple-jq-test" {

  program = ["bash", "./simple.sh"]

}
```

And my simple.sh file is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

function produce_output() {
  jq -n --arg arg1 "arg 1" '{"arg1":$arg1}'
}

produce_output
```

Why is it saying command not found, when jq is properly installed on my machine? Just trying to follow [this tutorial.](https://www.cloudwalker.io/2021/10/09/terraform-external-data-source/)

I was able to successfully create simple examples of Terraform external provider with PowerShell, the examples are [here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureWithTerraform/tree/main/iac/3400100-external-provider-ps-simple-example) and [here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AzureWithTerraform/tree/main/iac/3400200-external-provider-ps-rg) in my repo.

But when I try with bash and jq inside, I am stuck.

### Update 14-07-2022

When I use powershell, I get the error. But when I switch to bash(git), things are working fine.

Powershell screen shot.

[image: Terraform plan with Powershell]

And with git bash

[image: Terraform plan with git bash]

Finally things are working.

Comment: Your question should include all details required. Do not include links to a github repository

Comment: @Paolo, added sh file as well. Thats all to it. Let me know if anything more is needed. Its a fairly simple example.

Comment: Out of context question & suggestion. Any reason you aren't using WSL? You don't waste time on this kind of rabbit issue with Ubuntu WSL & you get superior developer experience with visual studio, WSL, ubuntu & any IaC tool. Very close to the execution environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are stuck because of the complexity of different shell coexisting inside you Windows environment.

You may have installed jq in Windows, that does'nt mean it is accessible from everywhere. For example, you successfully called it from Powershell, because Powershell "knows" where to find for executables, and to look at the one called "jq".

I don't know what is you bash setup (was it installed via Git Bash, Cygwin, Msys, WSL{1,2}), but you need to make jq available for this shell as well.
For instance, if your bash is on the "Windows" world, you may need to update the environment vaiable PATH to point toward the folder where choco installed your jq executable.

If your bash is in a Linux World (WSL), try to install jq in the right distribution you are using (for instance: sudo apt install jq if you distribution is Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, its via Git Bash. So how do I tell the bash to look for jq.

Comment: Locate first your jq executable on Windows, then append to your file ~/.bashrc (accessible from bash itself)

`export PATH="/c/PATH_TO_JQ/:$PATH"`

Make sure to convert Windows Paht into Unix path

Comment: Hi, When I used bash instead of powershell, things started working. See my update